# How to use multiple iOS versions in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am attempting to test my iPhone 4 running IOS 5.1.1 and in the organizer of xCode, when the phone is plugged in, it says that the latest available software version is 5.0 and I can't downgrade, all help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Get log in here: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and get Xcode 4.3.1.

Comment: Make sure you've got the debugging symbols for 5.1 in XCode's Preferences -> Downloads. (also make sure you've got the latest version of XCode)

Answer (score 1):

Update your Xcode from the App Store.